# When does apt-get update run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, optimization, apt-get, amazon-ami

I have been trying to optimize the update command to fetch updates from a local clone of the Ubuntu repo in order to optimize the download time and reduce the time taken by the enterprise firewall in performing a scan on every network packet.

In any AMI in AWS, when does apt-get update run? is it a part of the AMI code? or do we have to explicitly run it once the machine is started?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is not part of AMIs code. However we can't restrict AMI maker to not to do it.

It is good practice to run the apt-get update command in the bootstrap/user's data script explicitly when the machine is started.